# fields_for not working on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I think this is a stupid mistake… When i create a record, my "resources" and "page_settings" tables getting populated.

But my "page_setting" does nothing when i try to update the record.

My models:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :page_setting
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :page_setting
end

class PageSetting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource
end
```

Here is the resources controller:

```
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController
  # Initialize resource and belonging type model
  before_filter :build_resource_and_type, :only => [:new, :create]
  before_filter :get_resource_and_type, :only => [:edit, :update]

  def new
  end

  def create
    if @resource.save
      flash[:notice] = "Resource wurde erstellt"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "Resource konnte nicht erstellt werden"
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @resource.update_attributes(params[:resource])
      flash[:notice] = "#{@type_name} #{@resource.title} wurde aktualisiert"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:error] = "#{@type_name} #{@resource.title} konnte nicht aktualisiert werden"
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
  def build_resource_and_type
    # Get type from URL param (new action) or hidden field param (create action)
    type = params[:type_name] || params[:resource][:type_name]

    @resource = current_user.microsite.resources.new(params[:resource])
    @resource.type_name = type

    # Build belonging model depending on type param
    case type
    when 'page'
      @resource.build_page_setting(params[:page_setting])
      @type_name = 'page'
    end
  end

  def get_resource_and_type
    @resource = current_user.microsite.resources.find(params[:id])
    @type_name = @resource.type_name
  end
end
```

And the essential part of my resource form:

```
<%= form_for @resource do |resource_form| %>
  <%= resource_form.hidden_field :type_name, :value => @type_name %>
  …
  <%= fields_for @resource.page_setting do |page_form| %>
    <%= page_form.label :content, "Text" %>
    <%= page_form.text_area :content %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When i add @resource.page_setting.update_attributes(params[:page_setting]) to my update action it works… but i think it should work without this "workaround"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a small change in Your resource form:

`<%= f.fields_for :page_setting, @resource.page_setting do |page_form| %>`

Then it should work, like You want to.

Comment: This makes no difference, i still have to update the page_setting "manually" in the resources controller.

Comment: Can You debug and show how `params` looks like at the beginning of `update` in some simple example?